# emu8086 strange behaviour

Tags: x86-16, emu8086

I don't understand because there is difference between the original source code and the emulated code. (This happens after other strange things like: CMP that changes in a wrong way the flags). BTW here there is the screenshot. Thanks for the help.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBv9O.png)

Instead of:

```
MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H
```

There is something else

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough to go on without seeing the entire program. I have seen such behavior though in COM programs (using `org 100h`) where someone has defined a data section before the code but didn't jump over it. This lead to the emulator having a difficult time decoding instructions and doing strange things.

Comment: Thanks for the hint "someone has defined a data section before the code but didn't jump over it". It helped to solve